# Battlefield 4 crashes on launch

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4

Ok, guys, I just downloaded BF4 and it doesn't launch! I mean, battlelog works fine, but when I try to play the campaign or multiplayer, it  just crashes! It gives me a black screen with Window's message saying it stopped working!

Please guys, I really need your help here. I know BF4 is compatible with my PC, so it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Care to add a few details about your PC spec, OS, any specific error messages that appear when it crashes?

Comment: A screenshot of the error may help as well. Have you updated your graphics card drivers? if you have an integrated & a dedicated graphics card, is it trying to launch on the dedicated one?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I got it, it seems it happens very often. Just posted what worked for me. Thanks for the heads up, in my future questions I'll add more details! Have a great day!

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks! I got it, just see my comment above, I couldnt tag you 2. Have a great day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I did it!

First, I repaired the installation and then it wasn't crashing but it was now staying on the loading screen eternally. Then I found [this](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/PC-version-of-Battlefield-4-stays-on-loading-screen-eternally/td-p/1730165), and I followed some instructions and now it works just fine!

```
Navigate to your BF4 folder  "Origin\Battlefield 4\__Installer\vc\vc2012Update3\redist" and install the 2 apps. One of those, will ask you to re install

Anybody else got this problem update Punkbuster, drivers and then, repair the installation.
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If your using an nVidia graphics card or have SLi enabled I have found you can fix it temporary by changing the PhysX settings from auto to cpu or back to auto (dosent matter which). Then apply. The game will launch fine from that point until you reboot and you have to switch it again (it sucks but you can get it to launch at least). It dosent matter what you switch it to. I think something is not initializing with the GPU drivers and just making a small change (its really meaningless for BF4 because it does not use physx); creates a short term fix. Remember - you have to do this after every reboot usually. Repairing or reinstalling DirectX I have found does nothing since the game works after doing this small tweak in the driver utility.